# Internet Explorer ignores width when use CSS table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I created a js fiddle to illustrate the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/pLn7qgp7/

Actually this doesn't work in **Internet Explorer** - I set the width to `500px` but the browser ignores this.

I know I can simply add a width to the images but I search for another solution so that the image number can vary.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

IE is actually correct here. Chrome is wrong.

In keeping with HTML's history of backward compatibility, `width` on a table (or its cells) *actually* means `min-width`. Tables are free to width columns to make the content fit.

Add `table-layout:fixed` to the `table` element (in this case, your `#wrap` element) to force "strict" behaviour with regard to width.

Comment: I don't know who is wrong, but the complains are on the IE, not on Chrome

Comment: @Serge The fault is actually with the earlier versions of the HTML specification, which specified this "width on table cells actually means minimum width and you can expand to fit the content" behaviour. Internet Explorer followed the standard, Chrome did not.

Comment: How great is Chrome, that even not following standards meets the user's requirements. Most probably is a conscientious unfollow. If we see Edge, the "IE fixed", it behaves, as Chrome, non-standard, in a happy-user mode...